# How to resurrect old blog properly?

Tags: seo, blog, publishing

I've had a website long time ago and then domain expired and hosting vanished, I totally dumped it until now. Bought same domain again, made fresh blog and want to utilize all articles that have been written before (300+), I still have them in HTML.

So the question is how to do this for SEO properly?

Publish all blog posts with old publish dates in one day?
Publish all posts with new dates thoughout the month?

Comment: Just redirect old urls to new using rewrites.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to rebuild the old site exactly, making sure all the URL's are the same, it may be best to publish with the old dates. Of course, the dates don't really matter for SEO so long as the URL's are the same. It's up to you.

Comment: Some of the posts still have backlinks, I've republished them with old dates already but thinking of others I don't really have a clue which is better to start getting organic traffic to them.

Comment: It's not uncommon for people to go back and update old blog posts and republish with a new date. As I said, it doesn't matter what you do with the published time so long as the URLs are good.